# Set ng select dropdown model to null when model does not exist in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Assume I defined the following drop down in the UI:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items track by item.id">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
</select>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.items = [{name: 'item 1', id: 0}, {name: 'item 2', id: 1}];
$scope.selectedItem;
```

If I set `$scope.selectedItem` or the model to a value that exists in the items array e.g. `{name: 'item 1', id: 1}` then angular preselects `'item 1'` which is as expected.

But if I set the model to a bogus item that does not exist in the items array e.g. `$scope.selectedItem = {name: 'item 6', id: 6}` then angular preselects `'Please select...'` which is expected in the UI, but the model still remains `{name: 'item 6', id: 6}`.

For the example with a bogus item, is there anyway for angular to set the model `$scope.selectedItem` to `null` instead of `{name: 'item 6', id: 6}`?

In my case, the `$scope.selectedItem` object is being saved to the database so when it is loaded in the future, I cannot guarantee that the object will exist in the `$scope.items` array. If the object does not exist anymore in the array, I would like angular to set the model to null instead of retaining the stale object.

Obvious solution would be to check if the object exists in the array and if it doesn't, set `$scope.selected = null` manually in the controller but wanted to see if there was an easier or cleaner option.

**Solution:**

Opted to use a directive:

```
.directive('checkForNull', function() {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watchCollection('items', function(value){
        // if $scope.selectedItem does not exist in items array (value)
        $scope.selectedItem = null;
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: If the model is set to a specific value from the *outside* then you'll have to check at that time whether it's a "correct" value or not. There is no angular-sugar to help you here.

Comment: You should put the solution in an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor for your controller, you can just set $scope.selectedItem to null if the value does not exist in the items array:

```
$scope.items = [{name: 'item 1', id: 0}, {name: 'item 2', id: 1}]; 
$scope.selectedItem = ($scope.items.indexOf($scope.selectedItem) !== -1) ? $scope.selectedItem : null;
```

Comment: In my situation the model is persisted to the database. When `$scope.selectedItem` value is set to the object from the database, the object may not exist anymore in the items array

Comment: I have updated the answer to set the value to null if the value does not exist in the items array.